# How to use SQL Join operations with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Assume 7 tables like this:

**class_teacher_lesson**

```
class_teacher_lession_ID, class_ID, teacher_ID, lesson_ID
```

**class**

```
class_ID, class
```

**teacher**

```
teacher_ID, teacher
```

**lesson**

```
lesson_ID, lesson
```

**student**

```
student_ID, class_ID, ..., ....
```

**survey_answer**

```
survey_answer_ID, survey_question_ID, class_teacher_lession_ID, survey_answer
```

**survey_question**

```
survey_question_ID, survey_question,
```

Result should be something like this:

I will get this with a loop:

LESSON MATH:

```
survey_question (where teacher_id = 11 and lesson_id = 13):
Total Students            Total Students Answered Survey         survey_answer AVG
     155                                45                              79%

survey_question 2 (where teacher_id = 11 and lesson_id = 13):
Total Students            Total Students Answered Survey         survey_answer AVG
     155                                99                              87%
```

LESSON ENGLISH:

```
survey_question (where teacher_id = 11 and lesson_id = 15):
Total Students            Total Students Answered Survey         survey_answer AVG
     90                                20                              50%

survey_question 2 (where teacher_id = 11 and lesson_id = 15):
Total Students            Total Students Answered Survey         survey_answer AVG
     90                                25                              34%
```

So far I've tried this:

```
SELECT teacher AS 'Teacher', class AS 'Class', lesson AS 'Lesson',
COUNT(student_ID) AS 'Number of students',
COUNT(enquete_antwoord_ID) AS 'Total students answered survey', 
enquete_vraag AS 'Survey Question'
FROM Teacher
LEFT JOIN class_teacher_lesson
ON teacher.teacher_ID = class_teacher_lesson.teacher_ID
LEFT JOIN lesson
ON class_teacher_lesson.class_ID = lesson.lesson_ID
LEFT JOIN class
ON class_teacher_lesson.class_ID = class.class_ID
LEFT JOIN student
ON class.class_ID = student.class_ID
LEFT JOIN survey_answer
ON class_teacher_lesson.class_teacher_lesson_ID = 
survey_answer.class_teacher_lesson
LEFT JOIN survey_question
ON survey_answer.survey_question_ID = survey_question.survey_question_ID
WHERE teacher.teacher_ID = '1158' AND lesson.lesson_ID = '449'
GROUP BY class.class, lesson.lesson, teacher.teacher,
survey_answer.survey_answer, survey_question
```

With this results:

```
Teacher:  Class:   Lesson:  Number of students:  Filled in:    Survey_question:
t1        c1       math     54                   54            question1?
t1        c1       math     24                   0             NULL
t1        c1       math     22                   0             NULL
```

The results should become like this:

```
Teacher:  Class:   Lesson:  Number of students:  Filled in:    Survey_question:
t1        c1       math     90                   54            question1?
```

Comment: Please write the efforts that you made so far.
You can use `Join` operations with proper `Where` conditions in `Sql` query.
[This](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) may be helpful for you.
or try to read this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

Comment: What is your actual question? Have you tried something and encountered an error? Have you tried something and not got the results you are expecting? Do you not even know where to begin? I know there is a question in the title, but really the title should be indicative of your general problem, and your question needs to detail the specifics of your problem. At the moment you are likely to get answers that are just a guess at the problem you are facing, rather than actually solving your problem and (hopefully) showing you how to address similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
select survey_question, teacher_id, lesson_id , 
       count(1) as Total_student_answer_survey, 
       (select count(1) from student) as total_student,   
       count(1)/(select count(1) from student) * 100 as survey_percentage
from survey_answer sa
inner join survey_question sq 
    on sa.survey_question_id = sq.survey_question_id
inner join class_teacher_lesson ctl 
    on sa.class_teacher_lesson_id = ctl.class_teacher_lesson_id
group by teacher_id, lesson_id, survey_question_id
```

Comment: Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Ambiguous column name 'enquete_vraag_ID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Invalid column name 'Total_student_answer_survey'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Invalid column name 'total_student'.

Comment: In SQL-Server you cannot reference expressions in the select list by their alias, you have to repeat the expression.

Comment: Removed alias name. can you please check updated one

Comment: Nice jats, still have the first error though: Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 40
Ambiguous column name 'survey_question_id'

Comment: u can add sq.survey_question_id in group by..Sorry missing small things

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `enquete_vraag` in your select and `survey_question` in your question are actually the same column and it is just something that has been missed in translation (otherwise the query would fail to to selecting columns not in the group by).

In which case all you actually need to do is remove `survey_answer.survey_answer` from your group by clause (You can also change some of your left joins to inner, which could improve performance.).

```
SELECT  teacher AS 'Teacher', 
        class AS 'Class', 
        lesson AS 'Lesson',
        COUNT(student_ID) AS 'Number of students',
        COUNT(enquete_antwoord_ID) AS 'Total students answered survey', 
        enquete_vraag AS 'Survey Question',
        100.0 * COUNT(enquete_antwoord_ID) / COUNT(student_ID) AS 'survey_answer AVG'
FROM    Teacher
        INNER JOIN class_teacher_lesson
            ON teacher.teacher_ID = class_teacher_lesson.teacher_ID
        INNER JOIN lesson
            ON class_teacher_lesson.class_ID = lesson.lesson_ID
        INNER JOIN class
            ON class_teacher_lesson.class_ID = class.class_ID
        LEFT JOIN student
            ON class.class_ID = student.class_ID
        LEFT JOIN survey_answer
            ON class_teacher_lesson.class_teacher_lesson_ID = survey_answer.class_teacher_lesson
        LEFT JOIN survey_question
            ON survey_answer.survey_question_ID = survey_question.survey_question_ID
WHERE   teacher.teacher_ID = '1158' 
AND     lesson.lesson_ID = '449'
GROUP BY class.class, lesson.lesson, teacher.teacher, survey_question
```

However (although this is entirely subjective) I'd suggest cleaning up your query using table aliases, and also not using single quotes to identify column aliases (to avoid confusion with literals), and (this is even more subjective) I have added the SQL-Server specific `Alias = Column_name` syntax, which I personally find much more readable ([Perhaps some more eloquent reasons to switch are presented here by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)).

```
SELECT  t.teacher, 
        c.class, 
        l.lesson,
        [Number of students] = COUNT(s.student_ID),
        [Total students answered survey] = COUNT(sa.enquete_antwoord_ID), 
        [Survey Question] = sq.enquete_vraag,
        [% Students Answered] = 100.0 * COUNT(sa.enquete_antwoord_ID)  / COUNT(s.student_ID)
FROM    Teacher t
        INNER JOIN class_teacher_lesson ctl
            ON t.teacher_ID = ctl.teacher_ID
        INNER JOIN lesson l
            ON ctl.class_ID = l.lesson_ID
        INNER JOIN class c
            ON ctl.class_ID = c.class_ID
        LEFT JOIN student s
            ON c.class_ID = s.class_ID
        LEFT JOIN survey_answer sa
            ON ctl.class_teacher_lesson_ID = sa.class_teacher_lesson
        LEFT JOIN survey_question sq
            ON sa.survey_question_ID = sq.survey_question_ID
WHERE   t.teacher_ID = '1158' 
AND     l.lesson_ID = '449'
GROUP BY c.class, l.lesson, t.teacher, sq.survey_question;
```

Both of these solutions should give the same result, and I am not trying to force my preferences on anybody, I am just presenting options. It is just a matter of preference as to which you find more readable.

**EDIT**

I think you are getting cross joining due to joining multiple one-many relationships to the same "one", which is causing the null survey questions. I think moving the aggregates to subqueries may help:

```
SELECT  t.teacher, 
        c.class, 
        l.lesson,
        [Number of students] = ISNULL(s.Students, 0),
        [Total students answered survey] = ISNULL(sq.Answers, 0), 
        sq.SurveyQuestion,
        [% Students Answered] = 100.0 * ISNULL(sq.Answers, 0) / NULLIF(s.Students, 0)
FROM    Teacher t
        INNER JOIN class_teacher_lesson ctl
            ON t.teacher_ID = ctl.teacher_ID
        INNER JOIN lesson l
            ON ctl.class_ID = l.class_ID
        INNER JOIN class c
            ON ctl.class_ID = c.class_ID
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  Class_ID, Students = COUNT(*)
            FROM    student s
            GROUP BY Class_ID
        ) S
            ON c.class_ID = s.class_ID
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  sa.class_teacher_lesson_ID, 
                    sq.SurveyQuestion,
                    Answers = COUNT(*)
            FROM    survey_answer sa
                    LEFT JOIN survey_question sq
                        ON sa.survey_question_ID = sq.survey_question_ID
            GROUP BY sa.class_teacher_lesson_ID, sq.SurveyQuestion
        ) sq
            ON ctl.class_teacher_lesson_ID = sq.class_teacher_lesson_ID
WHERE   t.teacher_ID = '1158' 
AND     l.lesson_ID = '449';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply unfortunatly I'm not getting back anything at all without an error msg.

Comment: ON ctl.class_ID = l.lesson_ID
INNER JOIN class c
ON ctl.class_ID = c.class_ID

Comment: That was wrong but still I'm not getting back the right results 5 rows as a matter of fact I deleted class from group by and select but now I'm getting back 2 rows here a tinypaste with the output: http://tny.cz/6775a280

Comment: What DBMS are you using? The question was tagged with SQL-Server and MySQL, it is now tagged with neither.

Comment: I'm using SQL-server as DBMS, also students filled in must be 1 because in survey_answer there is only 1 row.